# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1 (Am I saving my file wrong in Java)?

Tags: java, arrays, file

I am trying to save a file line by line of a file in the form of:

```
number -> number
number -> number
number -> number
number -> number
```

etc. etc.

I have saved the file as the following (in Netbeans)

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\jon\\Desktop\\data.txt"));
String str=null;
ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
while((str = in.readLine()) != null){
lines.add(str);

}
String[] graph = lines.toArray(new String[lines.size()]);
```

I get this error when I run my function (code is syntax past storing the file line by line):

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   -1

at different places along my function. I'm assuming this is a problem because I am storing my file, wrong? Why?

Comment: The exception probably isn't happening in different places, but `stderr` (where the errors get printed out) is asynchronous, so different run occurrences will show it in different places of your output. Secondly, what about a line number? It's for sure in the stack trace. At least tell us which line so we can help you better.

Comment: printing e following exceptions of ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException will help. Check the size of lines.size() too.

Answer (score 0):

So you just want to read in line by line?
I'd use a file and a scanner, also for the array using an arraylist might be easier.

imports you will have to use

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
```

also use `throws IOException`

```
File fileData = new File("C:\\Users\\jon\\Desktop\\data.txt");
ArrayList<String> readFile = new ArrayList();
if (f.exists() && f.isFile() ) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(fileData);
    while (sc.hasNext()) {
        String line = sc.next();
        readFile.add(line);
    }
    sc.close();
}
```

This should work if you want to read in the file, but you mentioned reading them in as numbers, to do this we must use an arraylist of Integers and we need to parse the read in line to Integers, this can be simply done by replacing `ArrayList<String> readFile = new ArrayList();`
with `ArrayList<Integer> readFile = new ArrayList();`
AND `readFile.add(line);` with `readFile.add(Integer.parseInt(line));`

I hope this will help you out.